# ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g with eclipse oxygen, i am trying to setup Jdbc connection,
and i am using the connection statement

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:testuser/testuser@localhost");
```

I am sure that the username and password are right, but still i am getting

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:573)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:431)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:366)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:752)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:366)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at JDBC.main(JDBC.java:12)
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: You are providing no service name in your jdbc connection string. Is it intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try using this snippet taken from [JAVASE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html) tutorial:

```
Connection conn = null;
Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
connectionProps.put("user", this.userName);
connectionProps.put("password", this.password);

if (this.dbms.equals("mysql")) {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
               "jdbc:" + this.dbms + "://" +
               this.serverName +
               ":" + this.portNumber + "/",
               connectionProps);
} else if (this.dbms.equals("derby")) {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
               "jdbc:" + this.dbms + ":" +
               this.dbName +
               ";create=true",
               connectionProps);
}
System.out.println("Connected to database");
return conn;
```

EDIT: 
Or maybe you can try to specify the user and the password like this:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("
     jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:example", "example","password123");
```

Comment: i tried specifying the user and password, but i have a doubt, is the example after 1521:  (i.e., 1521:example) the user name?

Answer (score 0):

You have a default case sensitive username and password in the database. It is necessary to type the username and password correctly in the case sensitive or change the parameter of the authentication of Oracle `sec_case_sensitive_logon=false`.

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> show parameter sec_case

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- -----------------------------
sec_case_sensitive_logon             boolean     TRUE
SQL> alter system set sec_case_sensitive_logon=false scope=both;

System altered.

SQL> show parameter sec_case

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- -----------------------------
sec_case_sensitive_logon             boolean     FALSE
SQL>
```